# jQuery Mobile get value from two autocomplete UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two autocomplete search fields, and I want to extract the value from both. 
With one field I use ..`function(e, data) and data.input.val()`

But I've got one listener for two fields like this: `$("#search_one, #search_two").on("filterablebeforefilter", function(e, data)`

I've tried $("#serarch_one input").val(); but not working. Any ideas?

**html** //search_one

```
<ul id="search_one" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search one..." ></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vds2U/54/

#### HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a" >
    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>
            First Page
        </h3>
        <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a class="ui-btn" id="findVal">Find Value</a>
        <ul id="search_one" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search one..." >
            <li>sdfsdfsd</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', '#findVal', function(){ 
        alert($('.ui-content').find('[placeholder="' + $('#search_one').attr('data-filter-placeholder') + '"]').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you think of this? `var search = $("#search_one").prev().find("input").val();` For some reason it worked when I tried it... Slow performance?

Comment: Your solution is quicker then mine, My is slower but also works on older jQuery Mobile versions. Basically I choose compatibility over speed. Specially because listview is going to be redesigned soon. I forgot, if you intent to work only with jQuery Mobile 1.4 stick to your solution.

Comment: I guess your's is better than. I was just playing around :-)

Comment: No m8 your is faster :) , faster is always better, my example is here so any future jQuery Mobile user can use it without posting another question.